# Is it possible to determine whether a C variable was declared statically?

Tags: c, gcc, static

I have a struct type, which needs to be statically declared and persist for the entirety of the program.
`struct Foo`.

I also am writing the an API function to interface with that struct: `void bar(Foo *foo)`

The convention I have seen in other API docs is to just inform the application writer of this condition. However I am wondering if there is a check that I can do at the start of `bar` to verify that the struct passed was statically declared, and if not, exit?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's declared statically? It could be allocated with `malloc()`, and your function will work as long as they don't free it.

Comment: Define it globally (or globally static) and it will live as long as the program lives. Downside: there can be only one such object, given its name.

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you're asking. If you need a variable to exist for the entirety of the program, just declare it as a global variable or a static variable or, declaire it as a local variable in `main`. It's up to _you_ to determine the lifetime of a variable.

Comment: Sounds a lot like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: is there only one `struct Foo` or can there be multiple instances of `struct Foo`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: It is entirely clear what they are asking. They want a function (or some other facility) that, given a pointer to an object, returns an indication of whether it points to an object of static storage duration or not.

Comment: @wildplasser: That is not the issue; the function OP posits has no control over the definition of the object.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but not across all compilers and all systems, and not the same way on each of them. In short, it is not worth the effort to enforce this.

Just make the documentation for `bar()` be explicit that `foo` must persist.